# Rails Seeding with seed file broken into parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

I am following this example: https://obie.hashnode.dev/rubysinatra-and-organizing-your-seed-files

My directory structure is:

```
      db < folder >
        seeds < folder >
          01_user_seed.rb
          02_product_seed.rb
          03_images_seed.rb.
          seeds.rb
```

`seeds.rb` has the following code (per Obie Munoz's article, slightly modified):

```
      Dir[Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].sort.each do |seed|
        load seed
      end
```

When I then run `rails db:seed`, it fails silently.  I tried placing `raise` before and after the line `Dir[Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].sort.each do |seed|`and it doesn't 'raise'.

Do I have the code wrong? Or should the `Dir[Rails.root ***` be in the `config/application.rb` file and, if so, what should be in the `seeds.rb` file.

PS - The `01_user_seed.rb` looks like this (straight from Hartl's Ruby on Rails Rails Tutorial):

```
      p 'Seeding users...'
      1.times do |n|
        name = Faker::Name.name
        email = "ex-#{n+1}@4testing.net"
        password = "pass-#{n+1}"

      User.create!( name: name,
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                    password_confirmation: password
      )
      p 'Finished seeding users...'
      end
```

`rails db:seed` was working with `seeds.rb` before I reconfigured the code.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `rails db:seed` task loads your `seed.rb` file? Looks like no.

Comment: ```rails db:seed``` did load the ```seeds.rb``` file before I broke it into parts and added the code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation suggests your `seeds.rb` file is inside the `db/seeds` directory, it should be up in `db/seeds.rb`

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it.  Another set of eyes always helps!  I'm accepting your answer